# run basic file explorer with fix file in raspbian jessie lite the os without gui,

Tags: gui, omxplayer, jessie-lite

I would like to run a File explorer or a simple GUI without running the whole desktop gui. I want to use my Raspberry Pi as a simple dvd player, which run files by omxplayer command. video will be stored in memory card itself and have a very simple GUI for controlling this task with a few buttons. I don't want to install and run the whole desktop gui, because this will slow down the Pi.

I have installed raspbian jessie lite. and with omxplayer command i can run video file and display on screen.

now I want to  give access to user which file to play. for that I want simple gui, which shows files on screen. User will use arrow key, enter key, and back space key, to select the file, once enter key be pressed, video should play.

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Whilst it won't win awards you could take a look at curses style UIs. You'd have to put in a fair bit of effort, or find something preexisting. Python2 docs here https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

Answer (score -1):

There are so many os available, which do miminum gui for media, libreelec, openelec, kodi etc.

This fullfill the above requirement.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the whole question. Your answer would be better if it included details about what commands to run for OMXPlayer, e.t.c...

Comment: I am sorry bro i can not  do spoon feeding. All you have to do is install libreelec os, and there are thousand of tutorial how to work with that os. I can not paste all thing here.